# Ansible connect to windows host as local user - Errors 401/500

Tags: ansible, winrm

I get 401/500 Error when try to communicate with Windows host using Ansible.

```
[root@rhel7]# ansible windows -i hosts.ini -m win_ping -vvvv
<192.168.10.10> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: ansibleuser on PORT 5985 TO 192.168.10.10
<192.168.10.10> WINRM CONNECT: transport=plaintext endpoint=http://192.168.10.10:5985/wsman
<192.168.10.10> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: 401 Unauthorized.
<192.168.10.10> WINRM CONNECT: transport=plaintext endpoint=https://192.168.10.10:5985/wsman
<192.168.10.10> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: 500 WinRMTransport. [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
192.168.10.10 | FAILED => 500 WinRMTransport. [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

hosts.ini :

```
[windows]
192.168.10.10 

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansibleuser 
ansible_ssh_password=password
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
```

User ansibleuser is local and has local administrator privileges.
Ansible version is 1.9.2

I can successfully connect to the server with RDP, the winrm settings look correct, firewall disabled.

I used tcpdump to take HTTP-headers, request hasn't Authorization parameter. No ideas about it.

```
POST /wsman HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 0
Host: 192.168.10.10:5985
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python WinRM client
```

Please, help me with this issue, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason was mistake in official Ansible documentation: ansible_ssh_password is incorrect parameter, correct is ansible_ssh_pass

Comment: You´re right - had the exact same issue. But from Ansible 2.x on, the variable names have changed again: `ansible_user`,
`ansible_password` &`ansible_port`. `ansible_connection` didn´t change.